# Can delegate use a single methods for 2 delegates?

Tags: ios, delegates

The Question is this :

I have a view controller **Controller 1** which is a delegate of 2 other controllers **Controller 2** and **Controller 3**.

**Controller 2** has a delegate method called "FOO", **Controller 3** has the same method.

Can I implement one "FOO" method inside  **Controller 1** if both "FOO" methods tells the delegate to do the same exact thing ?

Thanks

Shani

Comment: can you post some sample code? I dont understand what "Controller 1 which is a delegate of 2 other controllers Controller 2 and Controller 3" means..

Comment: Why don't you try for yourself if it works?

Comment: It works, I know. I just want to understand the cons it there are?

Comment: Are controllers 2 and 3 instances of the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good delegate design means methods shouldn't have the same name. For example, if I have two classes called `FooA` and `FooB`, that both perform the delegating action `foobar:(BOOL)force`, then the delegate method names should be as follows:

```
- (void)fooA:(FooA*)foo foobar:(BOOL)force;
- (void)fooB:(FooB*)foo foobar:(BOOL)force;
```

This way, your 'Controller 1' will be able to differentiate between the two delegate methods. You will notice this in other delegates, for example `UITableView`:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

You're able to differentiate if `shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath` originated from a `UITableView` or a different class.

Saying this, it is entirely possible to have a single method name shared between two delegates, it's just the delegate won't be sure of the source of the delegation.

Comment: I think you mean FooB* for the 1st parameter of the 2nd method.

Comment: Plus 1 for the tableview example

Answer (score 1):

Can you do this? Yes. Should you do this? Definitely no. Assuming each of your view controllers is defining a protocol, the methods across all of the protocols should be uniquely named. In other words, if the protocol in **Controller 2** and the protocol in **Controller 3** both have a method that is simply named `foo` then you are doing it wrong. You should have `controller1foo:` and `controller2foo:`.

Here's why - while in **Controller 1** you may want to handle both of these the same, it is possible that in another controller you need to handle them differently. Or in the future you may decide that **Controller 1** needs to handle them differently. If both protocols define same method, there is no way to handle them differently.

Here's the proper solution. Give each protocol method a unique name. Then in **Controller 1**, implement both delegate methods. But the implementation of both delegate methods will be to call a common method that does the actual work.

In **Controller 1**:

```
- (void)doTheCommonWork {
    // This method does the common processing of the delegate calls
}

#pragma mark Controller 2 methods
- (void)controller2foo:(Controller2 *)controller {
    [self doTheCommonWork];
}

#pragma mark Controller 3 methods
- (void)controller3foo:(Controller3 *)controller {
    [self doTheCommonWork];
}
```

This approach lets you do the same thing for both delegate methods while still having the option of doing something different if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Are controllers 2 and 3 instances of the class?

So let's pretend that Controller 2 is a DoSomethingController and Controller 3 is a DoSomethingElseController, in this case you would want two different delegate methods.

If instead, Controllers 2 and 3 are of the same class or if one of the controllers' classes is, say, a subclass of the other then this is also okay. Example: `UITableView` and a subclass of `UITableView` could share the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate methods with one delegate object (Controller 1) and this would be just fine.